# Как скачать файл из cloud mail.ru через python?

Tags: python, excel, http, requests, mail.ru

Мне необходимо скачать файл из облака mail.ru, который находится в публичном доступе. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это реализовать. Максимум, что я могу - переписать страницу, но не скачать именно файл.

```
import requests
url = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/QZx5/d8dRiuKs1'
r = requests.get(url)
with open('smth.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам пишу подобный проект и мне тоже нужно скачать файл по публичной ссылке.

Нашел следующее решение:

```
    id = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/публичная/ссылка'
    part = id.rpartition('public/')[-1]
    name = id.rpartition('/')[-1]

    temp = requests.get(id) # Парсим всю страницу
    temp = temp.text # Превращаем байты в текст

    magic = temp.rpartition('"weblink_get"')[2].rpartition('"stock":')[0]
    magic = magic.rpartition('"url": "')[2].rpartition('"\n')[0] + f'/{part}'
  # Здесь из строки кода страницы вырезается та самая временная ссылка на файл
  # Возможно можно вырезать это лаконичнее, но меня устраивает такой вариант
    pdf = requests.get(magic)
  # Парсим контент напрямую и записываем в файл с названием "ссылка.pdf"
    with open(f'{name}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf.content)
```

Можно также запросом брать название файла с этого же temp и сохранять расширение файла, дабы автоматизировать и этот процесс на все случаи жизни, поскольку при попытке записать к примеру pdf в xslx у тебя получится битый файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getUrl(id): # id = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/публичная/ссылка'
    import re, requests
    first = re.compile(r"\"url\": \"[A-Za-z0-9\t\n:/.-]*\"")
    part = id.rpartition('public/')[-1]
    temp = requests.get(id)
    temp = temp.text
    magic = temp.rpartition('"weblink_get"')[2]
    res = first.findall(magic)[0]
    res = re.findall(r"\"[A-Za-z0-9\t\n:/.-]*\"", res)[1][1:-1]
    url = f"{res}/{part}"
    return url
```

Вот переписал код верхнего человека, так как у меня он не сработал, зато получился этот, ваша задача пописать requests.get(getUrl(id)).content или что-то другое(что вы там хотите делать с этим url?).

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```py
def getDirectLinkFromMailCloudUrl(link):
    # link should look like 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/XXX/YYYYYYYY'
    response = requests.get(link)
    page_content = response.text

    re_pattern = r'dispatcher.*?weblink_get.*?url":"(.*?)"'
    match = re.search(re_pattern , page_content)

    if match:
        url = match.group(1)
        # get /XXX/YYYYYYYY from source link
        parts = link.split('/')[-2:]
        # add XXX and YYYYYYYY to result link
        url = f'{url}/{parts[0]}/{parts[1]}'
        return url
    
    return None
```

Заметил, что когда нажимаешь "скачать" на странице по публичной ссылке, то браузер идет по ссылке вида `https://clocloXX.cloud.mail.ru/public/HASH/g/no/XXX/YYYYYYYY` а часть `https://clocloXX.cloud.mail.ru/public/HASH/g/no` лежит в объекте `window.cloudSettings.dispatcher.weblink_get.url`, который есть в верстке страницы.

Собственно, скрипт регуляркой берет это значение, подставляет параметры из исходной ссылки и возвращает из метода.